# Joomla folder permission denied

Tags: joomla, permissions, directory

I've a problem with folder permission on Joomla.
I run Joomla 3.7 on Apache+php-fpm (7.0) on Linux Centos 7 and all folder are set to the user the run apache and php-fpm (hotel:hotel).
All dir are chmod 755 and all file chmod 644.

This is my folder structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 11 hotel hotel      159 22 mag 10.49 administrator
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hotel hotel       44 22 mag 10.49 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hotel hotel       24 22 mag 10.49 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hotel hotel      119 22 mag 10.49 cli
drwxr-xr-x. 19 hotel hotel     4096 22 mag 10.49 components
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel     1959 18 giu 12.52 configuration.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel     3005 22 mag 10.49 htaccess.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  5 hotel hotel      118 22 mag 10.49 images
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hotel hotel       64 22 mag 10.49 includes
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel     1420 22 mag 10.49 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel       20 17 giu 12.59 info.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel 12714184 17 giu 12.16 joomla.zip
drwxr-xr-x.  5 hotel hotel       67 23 mag 15.47 language
drwxr-xr-x.  5 hotel hotel       70 22 mag 10.49 layouts
drwxr-xr-x. 11 hotel hotel      255 22 mag 10.49 libraries
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel    18092 22 mag 10.49 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 26 hotel hotel     4096 22 mag 10.49 media
drwxr-xr-x. 27 hotel hotel     4096 22 mag 10.49 modules
drwxr-xr-x.  2 hotel hotel       30 17 giu 12.15 php-fcgi-scripts
drwxr-xr-x. 16 hotel hotel      250 22 mag 10.49 plugins
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel     4494 22 mag 10.49 README.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel      836 22 mag 10.49 robots.txt.dist
drwxr-xr-x.  5 hotel hotel       68 22 mag 10.49 templates
-rw-rw-r--.  1 hotel hotel      264 18 giu 14.24 test.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel      346 17 giu 13.03 testu.php
drwxr-xr-x.  4 hotel hotel      246 17 giu 13.21 tmp
-rw-r--r--.  1 hotel hotel     1690 22 mag 10.49 web.config.txt
```

From Joomla panel only configuration.php and administrator/logs seems to be writable. All the other folders are not writable as shown below

[image: joomla system informations]

I've tested this php script:

```
<?php
    $root = getcwd();

    echo exec('whoami')." ";
    echo "$root ";

    echo is_readable("/var/www/html/cache") ? 'yes ' : 'no ';
    echo is_writable("/var/www/html/cache") ? 'yes ' : 'no ';

    echo is_writable("/tmp") ? 'yes ' : 'no ';
?>
```

This is the browser output:

```
hotel /var/www/html yes no yes
```

What could be the reason?

**I solved setting up SeLinux in this way**

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html
```